# Install Android APK as Mac OS X app

Tags: applications, macos

Is there a tool to package a particular emulator/SD configuration + APK as a Mac OS X application so that it can be distributed and run with a simple double-click? Something like Fluid for web apps... applied to Android apps on Mac OS (or Windows).

Comment: What's the problem with emulator of Android SDK?

Comment: Or [virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org) either and use the Android x86 project (which is what I imagine is how BlueStacks work) and install the apk on it, and distribute the virtualbox's image (size wise, I would think it would be about <512Mb so obviously would not be a good idea either!)

Answer (score 4):

[BlueStacks for Mac](http://bluestacks.com/bstks_mac.html) is currently in "alpha" testing, and is probably your best option at this point, although I don't believe it provides any kind of simple per-app packaging.